# How to combine two Tatkal tickets booked using one account?

Tags: tickets, bookings, indian-railways, tatkal, irctc

As per Indian railways rule on Tatkal, a total of 4 adult passengers are allowed to book on one train ticket.

Using my registered IRCTC ID, I have booked one ticket for me and my wife, and booked a second one for my mother and my two siblings. Unfortunately, the passengers on the second ticket don't have any identity proof. The passengers on both tickets have different seat numbers, but in same coach. Both tickets' confirmation messages are in my mobile's inbox.

Will there be any issue for passengers travelling on the second ticket because none of them have an ID proof to produce when TTE asks?

Comment: While booking the second ticket did you give any id-card information? As far as I know, you need to give id card information while booking Tatkal tickets in IRCTC.

Comment: No I hadn't given any ID card details while booking two tickets.The option is there to give but they aren't checking whether user had provided id information or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is writing after the journey.

I had convinced ticket examiner by showing the confirmation message received on my registered mobile number on irctc website after booking both tickets,that message has PNR number and passenger name of the booked ticket so that he wanted to see my identity card only.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Indian Railway rules](https://www.services.irctc.co.in/beta_htmls/etktfaq.html), one of the passenger booked on an E-ticket in a PNR is required to present the proof of identity while travelling. Since you have booked two separate tickets, each ticket will have its own PNR. So technically, at least one passenger from each PNR should have some document to proof his/her identity.

However in many cases, the ticket checker doesn't check the id-card and if you can convince him/her, you might be able get away with it. Since all seats are in the same coach, it should not be much difficult to convince the ticket checker.

Also note that their might be multiple ticket checkers since Indian railway keeps changing them based on the zones for long distance routes.